# Restructure Objects coming from Rest-Api

Tags: rest-api

I am working with wp-rest api and i have this json structure to work with:

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test-Font"
    },
    "acf": {
      "schrift": [
        {
          "zeichen": "A",
          "anzahl": "23"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "B",
          "anzahl": "46"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "C",
          "anzahl": "42"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "D",
          "anzahl": "49"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "E",
          "anzahl": "31"
        },

…


 {
    "id": 12,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test-Font2"
    },
    "acf": {
      "schrift": [
        {
          "zeichen": "A",
          "anzahl": "20"
        },
        {
          "zeichen": "B",
          "anzahl": "12"
        },

…
```

i want to load this like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/wordpress-dev/mi/wp-json/wp/v2/schriften/',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (element) {

    }
});
});
```

I want to achieve this structure, like an associative array:

```
[11]
  [A]:23
  [B]:46
  [C]:42
…
 [12]
  [A]:20
```

how could this be done?
can somebody push me in the right direction? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/9j96jbxn/1/

Replace your `data.forEach(function (element) {...}` with a nested for loop. This should get you close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is more about JavaScript than the WordPress REST API, but it's kind of fun to do and a good example of `Array.reduce`:

```js
var data2 = data.reduce(function(list, item) {
  var schrift = item.acf.schrift.reduce(function(obj, n) {
    obj[n.zeichen] = n.anzahl;
    return obj;
  }, new Object());
  list[item.id] = schrift;
  return list;
}, new Object());

console.log(JSON.stringify(data2, null, 2))
```

That and a less verbose ES6 example are in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joemaller/dga39bse/4/

The result looks like this (as JSON):

```
{
  "11": {
    "A": "23",
    "B": "46",
    "C": "42",
    "D": "49",
    "E": "31"
  },
  "12": {
    "A": "20",
    "B": "12"
  }
}
```

Note JavaScript makes it somewhat easier to loop arrays than object keys. Flattening into an array of objects with an `id` key might result in simpler loops later on:

```
[
  {
    _id: 11,
    A: 23,
    B: 46
  }, {
    _id: 12
    A: 20
  }
]
```